# How can I restore values via localStorage.getItem()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

this might be a newbie question but I did manage to save values in localStorage, which I would like to restore after reloading a browser. I did it with boolean or number values but I don't know how to save/load array.
Code I used in the process:

```
const storedPlayerChips = localStorage.getItem('playerChips');

if (localStorage.getItem('playerChips')) {
            this.setState({
                playerChips: +localStorage.getItem('playerChips'),
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                playerChips: 1000,
            })
localStorage.setItem('playerChips', JSON.stringify(nextState.playerChips));
```

[image]

Comment: When you retrieve the `localStorage` value, it will be a string, so you must convert it back  to an object with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playerChips'))`.

Comment: but how to deal with arrays like "dealerHand"? Because if I try a method you proposed I still got "null" after reload

Comment: To save an object to `localStorage` you need convert the object to `JSON` first:
`localStorage.setItem('dealerHand', JSON.stringify([{code: 'H7', image: 'some url'}]))`

Comment: If you are getting `null`, then you don't have what you think you have in `localStorage` or your variable is being overwritten. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(...))` is the correct method for retrieving anything other than a string from localStorage.